# Wordpress boilerplate plugin url parameter not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, boilerplate

I have a problem with jquery.
Jquery redirects to domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php + form values instead ajax_admin.php
I have other jquery calls with same url ajaxurl(ajax_admin.php) and they work.
This call is getting info from form but it seems that url parameter is not working.
Also it seems that action doesn´t go through also since it´s not in the redirected url.
Redirected url looks like this - domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?name=name&phone=phone
What am i doing wrong?

```
jQuery('#add_db').submit(function(e){
        var form_data = jQuery(this).serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {action: 'add_bookingdb', form_data},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data); 

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `ajax_admin.php` is your custom file location or something else?